# Arduino and PHP communication only work if I open the Arduino IDE

Tags: serial, linux

I have a problem. I try to open a channel to arduino and PHP talk, the PHP would send a command and the Arduino should answer that. It works, but only if I execute some steps before:

1. sudo chmod 777 /dev/ttyACM0
2. sudo arduino
3. Open the serial monitor in arduino IDE
4. Close the serial monitor
5. Now everything is ok, they can talk

The first step is ok, I really need to do this, the 2-4 seems irrelevant, but the communication do not start without it. I put one LCD in arduino to print what he receive, when I send "HEYARD" with PHP to him, the RX led blinks and the TX led also, but nothing is printed on LCD. If I do the 2-4 steps, when PHP send "HEYARD", LCD show HEYARD and arduino answer with "HEYPHP"

Anyone could help? There is some way to open it via Terminal, or, at least, open the Serial Monitor from arduino and close to see if this start

Comment: Does the PHP code set the correct baud-rate, parity etc.?

Comment: Yes, everything seems ok, the baud-rate is right, parity is "none", they can talk normally, but only if I open the serial monitor before.
I tried open the screen in terminal, but also do not worked, need to be the serial monitor.
Thank you

Comment: Try a proper terminal emulator like Minicom.

Comment: It could be that Arduino is setting the correct settings for /dev/ttyACM0, so others after it won't have to but should. Could you post the PHP code and `screen` command?

Comment: I tried use the minicom, until now, I could not read anything, but I will try make it start the port.

Answer (score 1):

Here the setup block:

```
<?php 
    require("php_serial.class.php");
    $serial = new phpSerial();
    $serial->deviceSet("/dev/ttyACM0");
    $serial->confBaudRate(9600);
    $serial->confParity("none");
    $serial->confCharacterLength(8);
    $serial->confStopBits(1);
    $serial->confFlowControl("none");
    $conect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or print (mysql_error()); 
    mysql_select_db("ANM", $conect) or print(mysql_error()); 
?>
```

And here the connection block:

```
<?php 
    $serial->deviceOpen();
    exec("echo 'HEYARD' > /dev/ttyACM0");
    sleep(1);
    $read = $serial->readPort();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

stty -F /dev/ttyACM0 ignpar
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 ignpar

> IGNPAR Ignore framing errors and parity errors.

That is what you need to fix minor framing issues.

Screen switches this by default; but NONE of the serial drivers do.
Especially when connecting PIs or BBB to Arduinos